# Alternative to PresentationViaCosetTable in GAP

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups, gap

I generate abstract tilings of surfaces, which are represented as graphs and use GAP to calculate the permutation group and based on that the finite group presentation using the following commands:

```
gap> di:=ReadDigraphs("/data/graph.ds6",1);
<immutable digraph with 450 vertices, 1500 edges>

gap> dg:=DigraphGroup(di);
<permutation group of size 5033164800 with 28 generators>

gap> pr:=PresentationViaCosetTable(dg);
```

Unfortunately, not even a server with 480GB of memory manages to find the finite presentation of the group.

In the GAP Documentation an alternative is described, which proposes to give a subgroup of the group in terms of words and generators to `PresentationViaCosetTable`. Unfortunately, my knowledge of groups is quite limited and I do not know how to approach this solution starting from my permutation group. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @Shaun Thanks for the input. I edited the question(s) accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PresentationViaCosetTable` is an older function that will be inefficien for all but small examples. I suggest you try
`IsomorphismFpGroup` (chooses generators itself to get a nicer presentation) or `IsomorphismFpGroupByGenerators` (takes your given generators).

When `hom` is such an isomorphism, let `F:=Range(hom)`, then `FreeGeneratorsOfFpGroup(F)` are the free generators and `RelatorsOfFpGroup(F)` the relators.

You also first could call
`hom:=hom*IsomorphismSimplifiedFpGroup(Range(hom));` to try to simplyfy the presentation, but that can be a question of luck.